# Value cannot be null with wkhtmltopdf in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to generate a PDF, it works perfectly in development, but not on my production server.  I assume it's a permissions thing.  The error I get is:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: fileContents

I assume it's talking about this fileContents param:

```
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File(Byte[] fileContents, String contentType, String fileDownloadName) +28
```

The code for the method is:

```
    public ActionResult Pdf(Guid id, string filename)
    {
        string url = Url.Action("RenderReport", "TitleSearchReport", new { id = id }, "http");

        var file = WKHtmlToPdf(url);

        return File(file, "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode(filename));
    }
```

The code that generates the file is:

```
    public byte[] WKHtmlToPdf(string url)
    {
        var fileName = " - ";
        //var wkhtmlDir = "C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\";
        //var wkhtml = "C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\wkhtmltopdf.exe";
        var wkhtmlDir = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(@"~/wkhtmltopdf");
        var wkhtml = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(@"~/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe");
        var p = new Process();

        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = wkhtml;
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = wkhtmlDir;

        string switches = "";
        switches += "--print-media-type ";
        switches += "--margin-top 10mm --margin-bottom 10mm --margin-right 10mm --margin-left 10mm ";
        switches += "--page-size Letter ";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = switches + " " + url + " " + fileName;
        p.Start();

        //read output
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        byte[] file;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int read = p.StandardOutput.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                if (read <= 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            file = ms.ToArray();
        }

        // wait or exit
        p.WaitForExit(60000);

        // read the exit code, close process
        int returnCode = p.ExitCode;
        p.Close();

        return returnCode == 0 ? file : null;
    }
```

Once again, it works perfectly when I debug, but not when I deploy.  What can I do to make this work on production?

Thanks for your advice.

**Edit:**

Changed my method to this, but now all I get is a blank page...

```
    public void Pdf(Guid id, string filename)
    {
        string url = Url.Action("RenderReport", "TitleSearchReport", new { id = id }, "http");

        var file = WKHtmlToPdf(url);

        if (file != null)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
            Response.BinaryWrite(file);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the Contents of `fileContents` after `var file = WKHtmlToPdf(url);`?

Comment: I am not sure how to check that in production.  I changed my code (as shown above) but now all I get is a blank page (no errors, just a blank, white page)!

Comment: Cant remember off the top of my head, but ages ago when I tried this, I had similar issue. Could you try writing to a FileStream instead of MemoryStream? I can't remember which way I made the switch.

Comment: There is an answer similar to yours here http://forums.asp.net/t/1819241.aspx/1 but I am not sure how to convert my code (which uses binarydata) to using a contentstream such as this.  Can you help with this?  Keep in mind, it works on development, but not in production.  I think this is more of a permissions thing, but...

Comment: Where does the file go when I try to create it?  Maybe I can just set write permissions on that folder?  I tried creating a `temp` folder in my root, but it still won't work.

Comment: **Update**  It seems my issue is solve by setting `read` permissions for the `NETWORK SERVICE` user on my root (www) folder...  Is this a security concern?  How can I make it write to `temp` or something like that?

Comment: **Edit:**  I also had to add write permissions to the root for the `NETWORK SERVICE` user.  Is this a security concern or is it cool?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to apply read and write permissions to my root for the network user.  Not sure of the security implications...